# iOS video playback

Tags: ios, performance, ipad, video, opengl-es

In my application i should play video in unusual way.
Something like interactive player for special purposes.

Main issues here:

- video resolution can be from 200*200px up to 1024*1024 px
- i should have ability to change speed from -60 FPS to 60 PFS (in this case video should be played slower or faster depending on selected speed, negative means that video should play in back direction)
- i should draw lines and objects over the video and scale it with image.
- i should have ability Zoom image and pan it if its content more than screen size
- i should have ability to change brightness, contrast and invert colors of this video

Now im doing next thing:

- I splited my video to JPG frames
- created timer for N times per seconds (play speed control)
- each timer tick im drawing new texture (next JPG frame) with OpenGL
- for zoom and pan im playing with OpenGL ES transformations (translate, scale)

All looks fine until i use 320*240 px, but if i use 512*512px my play rate is going down. Maybe timer behavour problem, maybe OpenGL. Sometimes, if im trying to open big textures with high play rate (more than 10-15 FPS), application just crash with memory warnings.

What is the best practice to solve this issue? What direction should i dig? Maybe cocos2d or other game engines helps me? Mb JPG is not best solution for textures and i should use PNG or PVR or smth else?

Comment: Why convert to images of any type? Why not just upload the raw frames as textures? Compressing frames as JPG or PNG images will be horribly expensive for video.

Comment: I prepare these JPG frames before playing video. I mean, i just use already created JPGs from files. Or you say, that i can use another (most efficient) format for my textures?

Answer (score 2):

Keep the video data as a video and use `AVAssetReader` to get the raw frames.  Use `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` as the colorspace, and do YUV->RGB colorspace conversion in GLES.  It will mean keeping less data in memory, and make much of your image processing somewhat simpler (since you'll be working with luma and chroma data rather than RGB values).

You don't need to bother with Cocos 2d or any game engine for this.  I strongly recommend doing a little bit of experimenting with OpenGL ES 2.0 and shaders.  Using OpenGL for video is very simple and straightforward, adding a game engine to the mix is unnecessary overhead and abstraction.

When you upload image data to the textures, do not create a new texture every frame. Instead, create two textures: one for luma, and one for chroma data, and simply reuse those textures every frame.  I suspect your memory issues are arising from using many images and new textures every frame and probably not deleting old textures.

Answer (score 1):

JPEG frames will be incredibly expensive to uncompress. First step: use PNG.

But wait! There's more.

Cocos2D could help you mostly through its [great support for sprite sheets](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats).

The biggest help, however, may come from packed textures a la [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/). Using PVR.CCZ compression can speed things up by insane amounts, enough for you to get better frame rates at bigger video sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Vlad, the short answer is that you will likely never be able to get all of these features you have listed working at the same time. Playing video 1024 x 1024 video at 60 FPS is really going to be a stretch, I highly doubt that iOS hardware is going to be able to keep up with those kind of data transfer rates at 60FPS. Even the h.264 hardware on the device can only do 30FPS at 1080p. It might be possible, but to then layer graphics rendering over the video and also expect to be able to edit the brightness/contrast at the same time, it is just too many things at the same time.

You should focus in on what is actually possible instead of attempting to do every feature. If you want to see an example Xcode app that pushes iPad hardware right to the limits, please have a look at my [Fireworks](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#Fireworks) example project. This code displays multiple already decoded h.264 videos on screen at the same time. The implementation is built around CoreGraphics APIs, but the key thing is that Apple's impl of texture uploading to OpenGL is very fast because of a zero copy optimization. With this approach, a lot of video can be streamed to the device.

Comment: Links broken, @MoDJ where can I find you example project?

Comment: Updated link and description, please try it now.